# Problems with uploading an app to the app store with pushwoosh sdk

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pushwoosh

I am trying to upload app via Xcode. I am facing below issue.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have added Pushwoosh framework manually (instead of using Cocoapods or Carthage), however you use the framework build that was released for Carthage distribution. The solution offered by @R.B. Niranjan should work.

Answer (score 1):

Pushwoosh framework is built for simulator also but now we have to delete unsupported architecture before uploading build on app store.

You can use the following script for removing unsupported architecture from release build.

> Open build phase -> Run script and add below script.
>
> "echo "Target architectures: $ARCHS"
>
> APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
>
> find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
> do FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist"
> CFBundleExecutable)
> FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME" echo
> "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" echo $(lipo -info
> "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")
>
> FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-tmp"
>
> case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
> *"iphonesimulator") echo "No need to remove archs" ;;
> *) if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "i386") ; then lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "i386"
> "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" echo "i386 architecture removed" rm
> "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH"
> "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" fi if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
> -verify_arch "x86_64") ; then lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "x86_64" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" echo "x86_64 architecture removed" rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" mv
> "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" fi ;; esac
>
> echo "Completed for executable $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" echo $(lipo
> -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")
>
> done"